# How to pass a QAction to a Qt slot from a QMenu

Tags: c++, qt5, qt-signals, qaction

Iam new in Qt and I have problem how to pass QAction as parameter like this code:

```
connect(fileToolBarAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(ToggleBar(fileToolBarAct));
```

And this my slots function:

```
void MainWindow::ToggleBar(QAction& what)
{
    what.isCheckable();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QObject::connect` doesn't work like this. You can not pass objects to `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros should take function signatures. In addition `the signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot` as described in the `Qt` documentation.

I see that you lack in understanding the signals and slots mechanism and I recommend you read the [Qt Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) documentation for more info. Reading the `Qt Signals and Slots` documentation will clear everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
onnect(fileToolBarAct, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(ToggleBar(bool));


void MainWindow::ToggleBar(bool checked)
{
    QAction* action = qobject_cast<QOAction*>(sender());
    if (action) 
         action->setChecked(checked);
}
```